# Create a SQL query based Daily report with Incremental Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cognos-10

I have a requirement to create a crosstab using a database which loads only incremental records. Please consider the following sample, Table1:

```
DAY         ACCOUNT NO  SALES   GENDER
1-Apr-2019  ACC01       5000    MALE
1-Apr-2019  ACC02       6000    FEMALE
1-Apr-2019  ACC03       7000    FEMALE
1-Apr-2019  ACC04       8000    MALE
2-Apr-2019  ACC01       7500    MALE
2-Apr-2019  ACC02       4000    FEMALE
2-Apr-2019  ACC03       10000   FEMALE
2-Apr-2019  ACC04       20000   MALE
3-Apr-2019  ACC01       8500    FEMALE
3-Apr-2019  ACC05       3500    FEMALE
4-Apr-2019  ACC02       9500    FEMALE
4-Apr-2019  ACC06       3600    FEMALE
4-Apr-2019  ACC07       4800    MALE
5-Apr-2019  ACC01       15000   FEMALE
5-Apr-2019  ACC03       12500   FEMALE
```

Table1 entries explained below:

1st April there are 4 accounts with their sale nos and gender of the account holder.
On 2nd April, there is some change in sale nos for all the accounts and thus they have been loaded.
But on 3rd April, we only load incremental accounts. As can be seen, the sales of ONLY ACC01 has changed and also there is a new account ACC05. Thus only these 2 accounts will be loaded.
Again on 4th April, existing account ACC02 has an increase in sale from its previous value and thus it gets loaded. Along with this, there are 2 new accounts, ACC06 and ACC07 which also gets loaded.
Finally on 5th April, we load existing accounts which have change in sale nos from their last value.

Now, I have to do a Daily MIS reporting and the result should be as follows, considering All my Accounts are Active as on 5th April 2019.

[image]

NO OF ACCOUNTS is actually the count of the Active Accounts at the end of each Day.

The above list Report 1, I was able to achieve using the following sub-query using Cognos Query/SQL items in Report Studio:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT D1.DAY, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D2.ACCN_NO) FROM
DAILY_TABLE D2 WHERE D2.DAY <= D1.DAY) AS NO_OF_ACCOUNTS FROM
DAILY_TABLE D1 GROUP BY D1.DAY
```

***Now, my requirement is to generate the following crosstab with a cut on the Gender.***

[image]

Best Regards

Comment: how we now an account is active that day ? Is there an `accounts`table ?

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry. I missed this question. Actually, this table is supposed to have both - Active and Closed accounts. But since I was trying to develop a query, I thought of considering Only Active Accounts. But, YES, there will be a Flag with 1=Active and 0=Closed in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split the totals easy by self joins, but I dont get how the `no of accounts` is setup. You will have to explain better.

To split up the sales you can use this

```
declare @sales table (salesday date, account varchar(5), sales int, gender varchar(10))

insert into @sales (salesday, account, sales, gender)
values ('20190401', 'ACC01', 5000, 'MALE'),
       ('20190401', 'ACC02', 6000, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190401', 'ACC03', 7000, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190401', 'ACC04', 8000, 'MALE'),
       ('20190402', 'ACC01', 7500, 'MALE'),
       ('20190402', 'ACC02', 4000, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190402', 'ACC03', 10000, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190402', 'ACC04', 20000, 'MALE'),
       ('20190403', 'ACC01', 8500, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190403', 'ACC05', 3500, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190404', 'ACC02', 9500, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190404', 'ACC06', 3600, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190404', 'ACC07', 4800, 'MALE'),
       ('20190405', 'ACC01', 15000, 'FEMALE'),
       ('20190405', 'ACC03', 12500, 'FEMALE')

select s.salesday,
       sum(sm.sales) as sales_male,
       sum(sf.sales) as sales_female
from   @sales s
  left join @sales sm on s.salesday = sm.salesday
                     and s.account = sm.account
                     and sm.gender = 'MALE'
  left join @sales sf on s.salesday = sf.salesday
                     and s.account = sf.account
                     and sf.gender = 'FEMALE'
group by s.salesday
order by 1
```

the result will be

```
salesday    sales_male  sales_female    
--------    ----------  ------------    
2019-04-01  13000       13000   
2019-04-02  27500       14000   
2019-04-03  null        12000   
2019-04-04  4800        13100   
2019-04-05  null        27500
```

Comment: Hi GuidoG - Thanks a lot for your reply. Your suggestion works perfectly and I am now able to get the correct day end SALES values. But I am still trying to figure out to get the correct count for NO OF ACCOUNTS considering that I have to report Total Active Accounts at end of each day. The Report 2 table nos is what I wish to achieve.

Comment: It was simple. I just modified the Report 1 query like the following and I am not getting the desired result in the crosstab table.  `SELECT  
DISTINCT D1.DAY, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D2.ACCN_NO) FROM DAILY_TABLE D2 WHERE D2.DAY <= D1.DAY AND D2.GENDER='MALE') AS MALE_NO_OF_ACCOUNTS,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D2.ACCN_NO) FROM DAILY_TABLE D2 WHERE D2.DAY <= D1.DAY AND D2.GENDER='FEMALE') AS FEMALE_NO_OF_ACCOUNTS 
FROM DAILY_TABLE D1 
GROUP BY D1.DAY`. Thanks to your direction. Appreciate.

Comment: Missed a group by in the above - `SELECT DISTINCT D1.DAY, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D2.ACCN_NO) FROM DAILY_TABLE D2 WHERE D2.DAY <= D1.DAY AND D2.GENDER='MALE' GROUP BY D2.GENDER) AS MALE_NO_OF_ACCOUNTS, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D2.ACCN_NO) FROM DAILY_TABLE D2 WHERE D2.DAY <= D1.DAY AND D2.GENDER='FEMALE' GROUP BY D2.GENDER) AS FEMALE_NO_OF_ACCOUNTS FROM DAILY_TABLE D1 GROUP BY D1.DAY`

Answer (score 0):

Just use cumulative sums.  The following generates all daily and cumulative values for males and females:

```
select salesday, count(*) as daily_cnt, sum(sales) as daily_sales,
       sum(case when gender = 'MALE' then 1 else 0 end) as daily_male_cnt,
       sum(case when gender = 'MALE' then sales else 0 end) as daily_male_sales,
       sum(case when gender = 'FEMALE' then 1 else 0 end) as daily_female_cnt,
       sum(case when gender = 'FEMALE' then sales else 0 end) as daily_female_sales,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by salesday) as cumulative_count,
       sum(sum(sales)) over (order by salesday) as cumulative_sales,
       sum(sum(case when gender = 'MALE' then 1 else 0 end)) over (order by salesday) as cumulative_male_cnt,
       sum(sum(case when gender = 'MALE' then sales else 0 end)) over (order by salesday) as cumulative_male_sales,
       sum(sum(case when gender = 'FEMALE' then 1 else 0 end)) over (order by salesday) as cumulative_female_cnt,
       sum(sum(case when gender = 'FEMALE' then sales else 0 end)) over (order by salesday) as cumulative_female_sales
from @sales s
group by salesday;
```

You can choose which columns you actually want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dfc66b8db381ea3acdd59502b5661015) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon. But cumulative is not what I am looking for. Incase of NO O ACCOUNTS, I was to report the total no of Active Accounts at the end of each day and the report 1 sql query is able to achieve that. TOTAL DAILY SALE on the other hand is the sum on Daily basis. In that same report one query, if I just SUM on that SALES column then I get the correct result. Difficulty arises when I try to get the Accounts and Sales by Male/Female.